# How to use all the available interfaces at the same time?

Tags: network-programming, udp, ubuntu-16.04

I am using ubuntu and for one of my project I am working, I want to use all the available interfaces at the same time (mainly wifi and wired). I don't want any kind of priority for that. Whether it will be better to manipulate the kernel code achieve this or manipulating routing will be good?

I can create separate routing tables for all the interfaces and use the accordingly.

Comment: When you ask your question, display the fact that you have done some research first. Try to find an answer by searching Stackoverflow. Try to find an answer by searching the Web.  Then display what you have learned in your question.  Read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

You can select which interface to use by calling the `bind` system call from your program, passing in a file descriptor, and binding to the IP address of each interface.

In other words, if you have two interfaces you would create two file descriptors, one bound to the IP address of each interface and then you could rotate between them in your program for sending data. You do not need to modify routing tables or kernel code to do this, just modify your program code.